# Why is $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^n,x_0)$ the trivial group in $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

My Algebraic Topology book says

> Let $\Bbb{R}^n$ denote Euclidean n-space. Then $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^n,x_0)$ is the trivial subgroup (the group consisting of the identity alone).

I wonder why that is. I can imagine infinite continuous "loops" in $\Bbb{R}^3$ that start and end at $x_0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have at least three unregistered accounts, all named "algebraically_speaking". I suggest that you stick to one account to better keep track of your questions. You can also register and subsequently merge your accounts. You might have to ask one of the moderators at this site to merge them, I'm not sure. As far as I know, you are also prevented to upvote or accept answers to your questions unless you register.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ be a loop in $x_0$, then
\begin{align}
H\colon [0,1]\times [0,1] &\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n\\
(s, t) &\longrightarrow (1-t)\cdot\gamma(s)+t\cdot x_0
\end{align}
is a continous map such that

1. $H(0,t) = H(1,t) = x_0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$,
2. $H(s,0) = \gamma(s)$ and $H(s,1) = x_0$ for all $s\in[0,1]$.

These are the properties of a *loop homotopy* between the loop $\gamma$ and the constant loop in $x_0$, *i.e.* $c_{x_0}\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R^n, s\mapsto x_0$. It is a continous deformation from $\gamma$ to $c_{x_0}$ while keeping the start and end point fixed.

Therefore $\gamma$ and $c_{x_0}$ are loop homotopic and the homotopy classes $[\gamma]$ and $[c_{x_0}]$ are equal. We conclude
$$
\pi_1(\mathbb R^n, x_0) = \left\{\, [\gamma] \ \big|\ \text{$\gamma\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ a loop in $x_0$}\,\right\} = \left\{ [c_{x_0}] \right\}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible (homotopy equivalent to a point). Hence its fundamental group is the same as the fundamental group of a singleton, i.e. trivial.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your last sentence is that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is not the set of loops based on $x_0$, but of *homotopy classes* of loops based on $x_0$.

Can you see why every loop in $\mathbb R^n$ based on $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$ is homotopic to the constant map based in $x_0$?